# Can one temporarily suppress a keyword in lstlistings?

Tags: lstlisting

I'm trying to write some pseudo code using the lstlisting package. The trouble is that I occasionally want to use the word "for" in statements such as "if x is of the form 2n for some n ∊ ℕ". And that occurrence of "for" is not intended to be a keyword. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please provide a complete, but small, example of code showing what the problem is.

Comment: IMHO, the `listings` package and the `lstlisting` environment are not suitable for “pseudo code”, as they are intended for “source code listing”. For instance, the `∈` symbol does not even belong in any type of code. You may have more luck with the `algorithms` package, the `algorithmicx` package and so on.

Comment: I've tried using proper algorithms packages. I just find all the "begin", "do", "end", etc. far too verbose.

Comment: Are you mixing your pseudocode in with regular code?  In that case, I would suggest commenting out the pseudocode.  Or is the entire code block pseudocode?  In that case, I would suggest creating your own listing language that has very little markup.  But if you have your statement next to a true for loop, I'm not seeing how you could tell listings that they are different for's.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Use emph={if} as an option if you do not want to have if formatted as a keyword.  This option is intended to emphasize words with a specific style defined by emphstyle=... Without providing an emphstyle, it formats the "emphasized" words in normal style.